# UITableViewCell Height Not Setting Up In StoryBoard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am having a strange issue that i am unable to solve. In my Storyboard, i have set the height of a custom UITableViewCell to be 100.

[image: uitableview cell height]

But when i run the program, the height is not hundred, its 90 and i don't know why. The issue wasn't there until i updated the project to iOS 7. It might be the AutoLayout but Auto layout was already enabled when my app was running on iOS 6 SDK.

Can anyone point out what could be the problem and how i can fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this the only cell that is supposed to have a row height of 100? If not, I'd try changing the row height attribute of the table view itself.

If this is the only cell, another thing I'd check is if any of your constraints were changed when the project was updated to iOS 7. If you have any ambiguous or conflicting constraints set, they'll show up if you click the yellow/red indicator to the side of the scene in question.

The last thing to check would be if you're calling

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

anywhere. I doubt that's the problem, but you never know.